# required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, autowired

When launching with mvn spring-boot:run or even with gradle returns that issue.

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field userDetailsService in webroot.websrv.auth.config.WebSecurityConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService' in your configuration.


BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 19.013 secs
```

Here are the main classes, all the requirements looks ok to me, I am using the org.springframework.boot release 1.5.7.RELEASE

```
package webroot.websrv.auth.config;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private JwtAuthenticationEntryPoint unauthorizedHandler;

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Autowired
    public void configureAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder
                .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Bean
    public JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter authenticationTokenFilterBean() throws Exception {
        return new JwtAuthenticationTokenFilter();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        httpSecurity
                .csrf().disable()

                .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and()
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(
                        HttpMethod.GET,
                        "/",
                        "/**/*.html",
                        "/**/*.{png,jpg,jpeg,svg.ico}",
                        "/**/*.css",
                        "/**/*.js"
                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        httpSecurity
                .addFilterBefore(authenticationTokenFilterBean(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);

        httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
    }
}
```

and:

```
package webroot.websrv;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class WebcliApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(WebcliApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Using Maven or Gradle it returns the same issue. All annotations and packages names seems to be as required.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Add a bean for **UserDetailsService**

```
@Autowired
private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

@Bean
public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
    return super.userDetailsService();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I also come accross this error. In my case, I have a class `JwtUserDetailsService` and I have forget implement `UserDetailsService`. After adding `implements UserDetailsService` the error was disappered.

Note that: if you also have own `UserDetailsService` and you use `Munna`'s answer, than you got error StackoverflowError it mean you also repited my mistake.

Answer (score 2):

In **Service class** make annotation

```
@Service
```

to

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
```

Answer (score 1):

Add @Autowired and @Bean Annotations for UserDetailsService in SecurityConfig class

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return super.userDetailsService();
    }
}
```

and

To allow circular references in application.properties

```
spring.main.allow-circular-references:true
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).